# How to use ranges as function parameter?

Tags: d

I would like to use a range as a function parameter, i.e. call something like:

```
foo(arr,1..23)
```

In the function I want to do something like

```
int arr[22]
arr[21] = some_other_arr[<range>]
```

where `<range>` is `1..23` from the above call.

Is that possible? How would I have to declare `foo`?

Comment: `auto arr[22] = ...` is not valid D code.

Comment: @DejanLekic: err... I always make this mistake...

Comment: You can't do `foo(arr, 1..23)` but you can do `foo(arr, iota(1, 23))` or similar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `1..23` isn't a range -- it's just special syntax that works only inside `foreach` statements.

A range that does the same as `1..23` is `iota(1, 23)` from `std.range`; it returns a range of successive values (such as integers).

To pass a range into a function, you generally want to use templates:

```
void foo(Range)(Range r)
{
    foreach (e; r)
        writeln(e);
}
```

Which you can then call the way you want:

```
foo(iota(1, 23)); // print the numbers from 1 to 23 (exclusive)
```

Note: if `arr` is an array, and you want a range of the values at indices `1..23` then you can use a slice:

```
foo(arr[1..23]);
```

A slice of an array is a range.

To have a function accept this, you don't need to use templates. `foo` could be written:

```
void foo(int[] r)
{
    foreach (e; r)
        writeln(e);
}
```

Comment: I wnat to use the range to access items in an `array`. I will edit the question...

Comment: Without reviving the entire question, I'd like to note you miss the template constraint. I think, it is fundamental for the understanding of how D works. For example, D defines interfaces "InputRange", "ForwardRange", etc. The problem with them as I understand: they only work with inheritance (classes). In order to support non-class ranges, you need template constraints (the "if-clause" between argument tuple and braces). The constraint freely specifies minimum template parameter properties (of range type) needed for instantiation. So use: `void func(R)(R range) if (isInputRange!R) {}`

Answer (score 1):

An array slice is the most powerful range - a random-access range. So why not simply use slice for what you need:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

int main() {
    int[] ina = [0, 1, 22, 11, 5, 9, 3];
    auto arr = ina[2..5];
    writeln(arr); // this is an example of a "function" with range as parameter
    return 0;
}

/*** output:
[22, 11, 5]
****/
```

You can toy with it here: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/95568985 (fork and run).
Frankly, I would accept Peter's answer because it shows everything you need to know. :)

Comment: What I want is to put the line starting with `auto arr` into a function and pass the `2..5` as a function parameter.

Comment: `myfun(2..5)` is not possible, as Peter already explained. `myfun(some_array[2..5])` is possible.